# Amazon Ec2 Data Transfer Out vs Data Transfer In

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I have read similiar questions  , But I am not getting any answers.I am planning to host a site with domain name at EC2.I am using https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html to calculate my price.

So when I put 10TB in Data Transfer Out is billing me $920 and Data Transfer In is free.

Currently I have 500 concurrent online users in my dedicated server.Its taking me 20 Gb bandwidth per day.So I want to know difference between Data Transfer Out  vs Data Transfer In.Which one is real bandwidth like 1million visitors visting my website.It is called out or IN.

Answer (score 0):

Data in is data users send to you - uploads and requests. Data out is data you sent to users - web pages, downloaded or streamed files.

I assume you mean 20 gigabytes (GB) per day - you said 20 gigabits (Gb). I've assumed 1GB per day in upload and requests, but data in is currently free. Every request has some inbound data, but for most sites it's relatively low. 20GB per day of data sent out from your server to the internet will cost you around [$54/month according to the price calculator](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html#r=IAD&s=EC2&key=calc-F0C7065D-938E-43B4-BC94-6A36994C121C). Yes you're right that 10TB of data per month will cost you around $920.

Comment: why is it so costly ? other cloud provide 10TB  free for $100 per month plan

Comment: Presumably it reflects the cost of providing that service. The Google Cloud estimates 10TB at $1136, Azure at $445, HostGator VPS at $750 with between 0.5 and 3TB included in their packages. You should choose the provider that best suits your needs.